# Customize pyuic's resource import statement?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, pyuic, rcc

When I use this command on windows:

```
python -m PyQt4.uic.pyuic user_interface.ui -o user_interface.py
```

After that, I add a resource:

```
pyrcc4.exe -py3 images.qrc -o images.py
```

And I end up with two beautiful files, **user_interface.py**, and **images.py**. The problem is that the **user_interface.py** file ends with this line of code:

```
... all QT stuff here.
import images_re
```

And because this is a module that is called from many parents, it has to be imported like this:

```
import myapp.gui.images_re
```

When I change the line of code it works perfectly, but every time I modify the user_interface.ui file and then execute the batch, it will be overwritten, and I will have to change it manually every time.

Is there any way to tell pyuic what to write in that import statement?
Or any batch code that can be executed after the pyuic and changes that line of code?
Or some tweak on the .py file that calls **user_interface.py** for example to change the default directory so it imports images_re from there?

Comment: [`--from-imports`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#cmdoption-pyuic4--from-imports).

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. Post it as an answer and you got it.

Comment: If you want to provide a more useful answer, you could tell me the shell code I have to use to convert ui to py using that argument, because I tried `pyuic.bat file.ui --from-imports "myapp.gui" --output file.py` and it says  `error: one input file must be specified.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you save the resource file in the same package directory as the ui file, then you can use the [--from_imports](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#cmdoption-pyuic4--from-imports) option. This will add the following import line to the ui file:

```
    from . import resources_rc
```

And the command would look something like this:

```
    pyuic4 --from-imports --output file.py file.ui
```

(NB: the `pyuic` executable name may differ, depending on the platform).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pyuic4 -h`, you can use the `--import-from=PACKAGE` option.

When you build the UI file, you should type:

```
pyuic user_interface.ui -o user_interface.py --import-from=myapp.gui
```

It worked for me.